# Using a C file in an xcode/objective-c project

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, xcode, import

I am making an iPhone app. I have a code that is in C. The C code contains a lot of pointers and global variables. I want to use this C code in my objective-c project. Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C is a perfect superset of C. Just add the file to your Xcode project like you normally would.